# What to do when confidentiality is violated by a member of Management

Tags: ethics

What to do if confidentiality is deliberately violated by Human Resources more than once?

What to do if this person is the head of Human Resources?

The head of human resources gives an employee's unlisted phone number  to individuals outside the company in this case former employees. The employee with the unlisted number and his family were victimized by multiple acts of violent crime (not related to employment -just to clarify-sorry about that). Then these individuals at the request of HR start a campaign of telephone harassment with the intent of coercing employees to disband a union during union negotiations. The HR person does exactly the same to other employees for the same purpose.

This is based on actual events. Three employees were affected by this incident and confidentiality was violated a total of 6 times.

Comment: You're going to need to give us a _lot_ more to go on, friend. As it stands, there's no context or information which we could use to give you any advice. It's like asking "what should I do if something bad happens?" It really depends on what that "something bad" is.

Comment: That edit changes a lot.

Comment: Get a lawyer and get help from the police. This is not something, people on the internet can help you with, this is a crime.

Comment: According to you, your employer is engaging in serious felonies against employees who threaten their bottom line.  You have three options.  You can turn a blind eye, you can leave, or you can fight.  Once you know which general approach you want, you can work out the specifics.

Comment: I clarified the violence issue- sometime I get ahead myself when posting. i edited my post.

Answer (score 6):

**Don't face this alone.** This is a matter for the union to deal with as a whole. 'Violation of confidentiality' is a rather smaller matter than what appears to be organised crime at the behest of your employer. It affects everyone, including the people who've not - yet -  been targeted.

> The head of human resources gives a employee's unlisted phone number to individuals outside the company, in this case former employees.

On its own, this is unprofessional and may be a breach of data protection laws. Its significance in your case lies more in the fact that it implicates the employer in criminal activities.

> The employee with the unlisted number and his family were victimized by multiple acts of violent crime.

In some countries reporting these things to the police is the most effective remedy. In others, it might not be, depending on how corrupt the police are. Consult with your union and (if your union is just getting started) other unions in the same area. Your union should have or be looking to have on retainer a legal advisor - talk to them.

> Then these individuals at the request of HR start a campaign of telephone harassment with the intent of coercing employees to disband a union during union negotiations. The HR person does exactly the same to other employees for the same purpose.

You should make sure your colleagues are aware that they should expect dirty tactics, and have an action plan. Make sure they know what to do if they are being called, threatened, victims of crime at home etc. There's a balance to be struck - don't scare people, just make them feel confident enough that they know what to do and won't panic.

The struggle to become a recognised union is often the hardest. You need to make sure all your members feel they're in this together, not individually victimisable and vulnerable. If the threats and violence do not immediately stop once reported to the police (or if going to the police isn't an option) or after your union reps have made it clear that this behaviour is unacceptable, you are going to have to make a *collective* decision on what industrial action to take. Ultimately, your union negotiation is predicated on your ability to make collective decisions, including taking industrial action, to defend and support each other.

Comment: I don't agree with leave it to the union.  The union will represent the union - not the individuals.  Given they were victimized by multiple acts of violent crime there may be some personal damages here also.

Comment: `In some countries reporting these things to the police is the most effective remedy. In others, it might not be, depending on how corrupt the police are.` It also depends on how busy they are, and how much they care about what could written off as a minor offense.

Comment: @Paparazzi - I didn't say "leave it to" the union - use the union; it's not *merely* an individual matter if the employer is using it widely. Typically a union will advise members on their relevant avenues - internal, industrial, criminal, and civil.

Answer (score 2):

IANAL You should talk to an attorney.  That goes beyond a simple confidentiality breach to intent to do harm (in my opinion).  Unions have protection from meddling / coercion - let your union know.  Again IANAL but even 3 can form a class action suit.

The union is going to represent the union (not the individuals).  The employee with the unlisted number and his family were victimized by multiple acts of violent crime. That is personal damages. Let an attorney tell you if you have a personal case.

Comment: Talking to a lawyer sounds like something the employer might retaliate in response to.  Not saying it's bad advice, just saying that's something OP should consider.

Comment: @HopelessN00b And just how is the employer going to know you talked to a lawyer?

Comment: Well, as soon as the lawyer actually does anything, they'll know.  Getting served is usually a substantial tip-off, and it's not like you can sue someone anonymously.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Lawyer do something and talking to a lawyer for advice are NOT the same.  Lawyer will not do something without your approval.

Answer (score -2):

@user52889 & Paparazzi:

This issue was resolved quite successfully. This issue happened in Canada more specifically in the province of Quebec.

In a large companies there are employees who ally themselves with HR ie: toadies. You have to be very careful and deal with people you know and can trust otherwise this can backfire on you.

There is actually a process that you need to follow before go to attorneys  and law enforcement. One must exhaust all internal complaint processes. For example you must contact the individual in writing then escalate further up the chain of command. One of the reasons is for documentation to prove your case.

The email sent to the person in question was about 750 words in length and was extremely graphic and explicit outlining the reason why the number was unlisted and defined the impact of these actions had on my family. No detail was excluded. This individuals response was only 10 words in length.

The individuals that I escalated to was the vice-president and president of the company. Suffice it to say they were not impressed with that individual. 
Upon receiving the complaint they had no choice but to terminate the person for just cause. Failure of the company to do would have the company accomplices in criminal activity.  I received an personal apology from the president of the company in front of all my co-workers.

Going to a lawyer in the beginning against a person in management is a futile effort. The person would have access to a company legal whereas the employee pays out of pocket. It would be more to the point to wait for this person to be fired and pay for their own lawyer.

Theoretically,If I had the fund to pursue it in a court of law. The individual could have face 2 counts of stalking (criminal harassment). 
Telephone harassment becomes stalking when the individual affected has legitimate concerns for the safety of themselves and their family.

Effectively because of this I saved the company upwards of 250K in salaries and fines.

Comment: Don't agree there a process that you need to follow before go to attorneys and law enforcement.  An attorney could advise you to exhaust all internal complaint processes.   Clearly you can report acts of violent crime to the police in Canada.  First you give no detail to the question and then you already had an answer.  I feel little used here.

Comment: My employer was not the one who committed the acts of violence. The violent crime was prosecuted  and the perpetrator did time in prison.  In Quebec there are processes laid out in the law that must be followed.. There are laws in Canada pertaining to whistle blowing on your employer. My intent was to see if other people have had to deal with this in other countries and what the recourses were and their effectiveness. My answer was how I dealt with it.

Comment: Really inciting an act of violence is immune from cause?  B.S. you have to exhaust all internal complaint processes before you can report a violent crime to law enforcement.

Comment: The violence crime was not related to anything to the workplace or anyone at the workplace. My phone # became unlisted at the request of the police. The crime victims were 2 close members of my family. The only crimes at the workplace were  criminal invasion of privacy and stalking. If at the time I had the wherewithal and funds to escalate further I would have. The events at work happened very shortly after the perpetrator was released on parole. I was somewhat overwhelmed.

Comment: So now the violent crime was not even related to the workplace.  Then why even mention it?   Not cool.